# Telegram bot send messages periodically

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am trying to get my bot to send a message to the user periodically but I'm getting the error below. What am I doing wrong?

code:

```
import telegram.ext
from telegram.ext import Updater
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler

def callback_minute(update: telegram.Update, context: telegram.ext.CallbackContext):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id= update.effective_chat.id, 
                             text='One message every minute')

def main():
    u = Updater('TOKEN', use_context=True)
    j = u.job_queue
    job_minute = j.run_repeating(callback_minute, interval=60, first=0)
    u.start_polling()

main()
```

Error:

```
TypeError: callback_minute() missing 1 required positional argument: 'context'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [transition guide to version 12.0](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Transition-guide-to-Version-12.0#job-callbacks) has a small section about job callbacks. It especifies only `context` (CallbackContent object) as a parameter for the callback function, which includes `bot` and `job`.

```
def callback_minute(context: telegram.ext.CallbackContext):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=SOMECHATID, text='One message every minute')
```

As you can see, you need to especify a `chat_id` in `SOMECHATID`.

The [wiki](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-JobQueue) has a small tutorial. If you take a close look you will see that the job callback only uses `context`, the other function callback is to handle the `/timer` command invoked by someone, hence the use of `update` and `context`.